# strange exception in WebDrive when add_cookie is used

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver, urllib2

my code is something like that:

```
response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
cookieValue = response.info()["Set-Cookie"]
cookie = {'Set-Cookie': cookieValue}

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(innerPageOfTheSameRequest)
print cookie
driver.add_cookie(cookie)
```

The cookie is printed as expected:

> {'Set-Cookie': 'SessionID_R3=dXM0ChrdPhYUhfL1drI2eP9r6Wjha8tX943Sv8CZp0v6LQ2v1/m
>   u3y/h839tX0zGJ36VtBsIY4EJaxlr78g9gokEfz6HA7wvXb7ECo8nRjXjO0+Ty/E5IC64BseItDk; pa
>   th=/; HttpOnly;'}

But I get an excpetion on the last line:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "p.py", line 80, in 
>       driver.add_cookie(cookie)
>     File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 634, in add_cookie
>       self.execute(Command.ADD_COOKIE, {'cookie': cookie_dict})
>     File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 201, in execute
>       self.error_handler.check_response(response)
>     File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py"
>   , line 194, in check_response
>       raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
>   selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: name of cookie is missing or invalid:"undefined"
>     (Session info: chrome=48.0.2564.116)
>     (Driver info: chromedriver=2.21.371459 (36d3d07f660ff2bc1bf28a75d1cdabed0983e7c4),platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86_64)

Someone can help me to understand what I'm doing wrong ?
Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your cookie doesn't have the right format. According to [the documentation](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.add_cookie) the argument to `add_cookie()` is

> cookie_dict: A dictionary object, with required keys - “name” and
>   “value”;

You have neither of these keys but instead have a Set-Cookie header.

Your cookie should probably be

```
{'name': SessionID_R3,
 'value' : 'dXM0ChrdPhYUhfL1drI2eP9r6Wjha8tX943Sv8CZp0v6LQ2v1/m u3y/h839tX0zGJ36VtBsIY4EJaxlr78g9gokEfz6HA7wvXb7ECo8nRjXjO0+Ty/E5IC64BseItDk',
 'path' : '/'}
```

I'm not sure if you can get `HttpOnly` as it isn't mentioned in the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

I hit the same error using code like

```
pickle.dump(driver.get_cookies(), open(cookie_file, "wb"))
cookies = pickle.load(open(cookie_file, "rb"))
driver.add_cookie(cookies)
```

I wasn't paying close attention where I have a cookie vs many cookie**s**.

```
for c in cookies:
    driver.add_cookie(c)
```

Resolved the issue. `HttpOnly` was a red herring here. add_cookie took a dict with that and many other keys just fine.